# chat with quickblox using special characters iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I currently facing very strange issue with Quickblox, please anybody have any idea about this issue, help me out.

I am doing one to one chat and created private dialog for that.
I am sending message one user to other user like below:

```
QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
[message setText:@"Hello"];
message.dialogID = qb_dialog_id;

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"send_to_chat"] = @"1";

[message setCustomParameters:params];


[QBRequest createMessage:message successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatMessage *createdMessage) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", createdMessage);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", response.error);
    }];
```

This is work fine for me even any for special characters like "*,'$#!
And user will receive this messages whom i send the message from the delegate of quickblox method

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message
```

Now the issue is, when i am sending message with '&' character other user will not get this message and my chat is also stop working and also not even call the delegate of receiver side.

But it is storing in the quickblox history that is in Chat module. So what is the issue with the **'&'** in **QBRequest**

Comment: see this link it helps you https://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios